# dynamic mysql query in c++

Tags: c++, mysql

i have a query ->

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'hello2.csv' 
INTO TABLE failure_report.master_entry
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 2 ROWS
```

in c++ i have->

```
string h1="hello2.csv";
string h2;
ostringstream strstr;
strstr << "LOAD DATA INFILE'" << h1 << "'INTO TABLE failure_report.master_entry    FIELDS  TERMINATED BY'"<<","<<"'ENCLOSED BY '"<<'"'<<"'LINES TERMINATED BY '"<<"\n"<<" '  ignore 2 rows";
h2=strstr.str();
int query_state=mysql_query(con,h2.c_str());
```

mysql_query does return 0 but the database is not updated.mysql_error is null.

Comment: Please provide output from [`mysql_error()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-error.html)

Comment: now thats worked now mysql_query is returning 0 but my database is not getting updated.

Comment: That should be comment to answer, not the question :) But anyway, what's the output of `printf("Executing query: %s", h2)` or `std::cout << h2 << std::endl;` (whichever you prefer)? What does happen if you run query directly from mysql client? Do you commit data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing spaces between some words and apostrophes `'` and escape for `\n` (it also has special meaning in C++ and only literal new line gets send to mysql server, you have to use `\\n`), try using:

```
strstr << "LOAD DATA INFILE '" << h1 << "' " 
       << "INTO TABLE failure_report.master_entry "
       << "FIELDS  TERMINATED BY ',' "
       << "ENCLOSED BY '\"' "
       << "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' "
       << "IGNORE 2 ROWS";
```

Also note the space before every `"` in the end of the line.

In future use `printf("Executing query: %s", h2)` and [`mysql_error()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-error.html) for debugging.

Comment: i have got some things fixed but now new problem has arised.plz look at the question

Comment: @user3819404 What does happen if you run query directly from mysql client? Do you commit data?

Comment: yes thats working perfectly if i run in mysql client

Comment: what about if you add `mysql_query(con,"COMMIT;");` ?

Comment: @user3819404 what about number of affected rows reported by it, what about show warnings?

Comment: i dont know but the problem is solved .i used your version of the above query and it worked..i have to find out why, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem is with the way you are using opening and closing `'` quotes around statements, and excaping `"`.

```
strstr << "LOAD DATA INFILE '" << h1 << "' INTO TABLE failure_report.master_entry FIELDS  TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' ignore 2 rows";
```